# How can we stop Lightning Components changing GlobalIDs?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm in a need to place a Lightning Component multiple instances on single page (such as Home Page) but I need the options or filters sticky for the component instance only.

I tried using `GlobalID`, but it changes with every page refresh.

Anyone have any idea how to make them sticky for an instance of the component on page?

Comment: why not use events to communicate between the components?

Answer (score 0):

Global Id is not static and as you have already faced changes with every refersh.

*from docs:*

> Every component has a unique globalId, which is the generated
>   runtime-unique ID of the component instance. A global ID (1) is not
>   guaranteed to be the same beyond the lifetime of a component, so it
>   should never be relied on. A global ID can be useful to differentiate
>   between multiple instances of a component or for debugging purposes.

So the only thing which you can try here is use html component and create there global Id manually.

```
<div id="{!globalId + '_footer'}"></div>
```

[Component IDs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_ids.htm)

Comment: Problem is, I've 2 instances on page. Then I need to find which instance is which, inside that index. `{globalId + '_footer'}` will return different `globalId`. I need to find instance, and then save & retrieve the sticky options I want to put in UI for that instance of component only.

Comment: @VarunC in globalId you can pass variable 1,2,3... so on.

Comment: The cmp is to be placed from App Builder. I see, your point is suitable if I'm placing the component in another component and I pass the `globalId` as attribute value?